# Policy for owner-only record visibility

Tags: kinto

I am considering to use Kinto to provide a storage backend for user-created/-managed data.

However, all examples I have seen in the docs only talk about "everyone can read" scenarios. In my case, each user should only see their own records, unless some are explicitly shared by others or made visible to everyone explicitly from the backend/admin side.

Is there an example of such a policy or an easy way to describe/add it to Kinto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All what you need, just create collection with permission:

```json
{
 "permissions": {
    "record:create": ["system.Authenticated"]
  }
}
```

and create record.

Every user will see only personal records which he created, so  you must be authorized as `alice` to see records with `{"permissions": {"write": [ "account:alice"]}` in `../records` endpoint listing or get it by `id`

Comment: OK, so each record will also need to have a permission like "read" → "system.Authenticated" if I want the specific record to be shared with all other authenticated users, correct? So essentially, there is be no "inherited default" I could set?

Comment: yes, or you can set `"read": ["system.Authenticated" ]` to collection